# Terminal app Tabs, how to position next to current tab instead of at the end

Tags: terminal, tabs

I use Cmd-T all the time to open new tabs, and it's set to use the same directory.

However, it positions the new tab as the last / far right tab in the window, instead of next to the current tab that I'm in.  Since it's often related to what I'm working on, I'd like to appear right next to the current tab.

Is there a setting for this?  (found lots of things about Terminal and Tabs, but not this specific question)

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a feature request or a bug report. Please file one at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/. You can use any Apple ID with the developer website.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible in nightly release of the alternative terminal program [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) via *Preferences* → *Advanced* → *Tabs: New tabs are added at the end, not next to current tab* set to *No*.

Comment: Could you comment on whether iTerm2 is a complete replacement for Terminal? I realize this is a little subjective…

Comment: Absolutely. I moved to iTerm2 few years ago and had never regret. Good explanation is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25146/128583

Comment: I downloaded iTerm2 2.0 (the current stable build from their site) and I don't see the tab placement option you mention.  Under the main Preferences, there isn't any "Advanced" option anymore.  And under Profiles, although there is an Advanced section, I don't see tab placement on there either.  Can you please recheck your answer against the current download?  (maybe I'm looking right at it and just not seeing it)

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention I use nightly version, which has mentioned option available.

Comment: It's not available in the iTerm2 2.1.1 beta either, so Nightly it is. Hopefully last night was a bug-free one :)

Comment: Oh, OK, so "Coming soon to a terminal near you!" - guys, I really appreciate the answers, and to see activity on this thread. <- @AhmedFasih and Vadzim

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple has changed this behavior, somewhere in the High Sierra updates, so that now the new terminal comes up next to the one I'm in - cool!